# What method are there to explore varying element to attribute results in XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am in the process of data exploration and have given (varied) XML in SQL Server. There are about 1,500 records with a header record, load date and RAW_XML column. In that XML column there are varying records; x num of elements, within those elements, x num of attributes. Within each record there are not fixed num of elements; there are some repeated elements and in other records new elements. If there are repeated elements in a record there can be a few attributes to that element and at other times many attributes to it.

I have consulted many XML related articles, methods in querying etc. but these demonstrate doing so by fixed elements and attributes. I am not sure how to do this with such varied data. Is there an exploratory method that I have not considered here?

[image: Example of scenario]

Comment: Without sample data, and expected results, and what you've tried (and why it didn't work), there is very little we can do to help you here.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? *I have any kind of complex XML and I want to read it in a meaningful way* This would need magic... Well, there are approaches to read *each and everything* in kind of *EAV-list*, but this won't be very helpful. Try to pick some representative examples, reduce them to a senseful minimum, use [edit] to add more details to your question and state the expected output. Thx

Comment: Sure, initially wasnt sure to include example or not. Ive attached an image and will include python tag curious if this is option. The image shows 3 instances of the element MemberInfo with diff attributes, and in the XML column there may no instances of MemberInfo. This applies to a couple hundred attributes. The uncertaintly is what is the best way to examine the XML to get a feel for attributes within the sample data sets, there are 1,000 or so records and I want to capture all. Must I drill into, or query each XML field, audit elements and attributes one by one? Is Python an option here?

Comment: @SuraAnahita please post your xml for *copy n paste*. And please avoid pictures... After looking at your sample this seems to be rather easy. At least the samples are quite similar.